# Getting nullable type of dynamic object

Tags: c#

Is it possible to find out at run-time that dynamic object is returning a `Nullable` type?

In my case it can return any type and I need to figure out what the type is. Usually `GetType()` works well, but for `Nullable` objects it returns the underlying type instead of actual `Nullable` type.

```
        dynamic d1 = DateTime.Now;            
        Type type1 = d1.GetType();

        dynamic d2 = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now;
        Type type2 = d2.GetType();
```

The returned type for both is exactly the same `System.DateTime`

Is there any way to figure out that the actual type is `Nullable`?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The actual type of `d` *is* `DateTime`.  It really *isn't* `Nullable<DateTime>`.